# How do I install the Rainbow Pack?

Tags: xbox-360, lego-batman-3

When I preordered Lego Batman 3: Beyond Gotham for Xbox 360, I received a code for the "Rainbow Pack" DLC.  I activated it using the [Xbox website](https://account.xbox.com/en-AU/PaymentAndBilling/RedeemCode?xr=mebarnav).

However, I now can't find any way to tell the system to download it - it doesn't appear on the list of DLC linked on the main menu, for example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you activated the code on the Xbox website, it will have been associated to your Microsoft account, as well as the first Xbox 360 your account logs into afterwards.

The content *should* have been downloaded instantly to this Xbox 360 if it was online.

You should check your account history on the xbox to make sure it was associated to the correct account and then download it again.

This is found in *Settings -> Account -> Download History*.

http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/downloadable-content/view-download-history

If it happens that it was associated to the wrong account by accident, as long as the first xbox used by the associated account is the same one you are trying to play the content on, everyone on that Xbox should be able to use the content.